# Creating a file and settimng metadata at the same time in Firbase Storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

i am currently working on a react app which uses Firebase Storage to store files.
My problem is: i want to create a file and attach metadata to it before storing it on Firebase storage;
as far as i know, now i have to

1. save the file in the storage creating the file ref
2. take the ref of that file, set metadata and upload it.

is there a way to make these 2 steps into 1?

Thanks in advance for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the Cloud Storage for Firebase [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#add_file_metadata), "when uploading a file, **you can also specify metadata for that file**".

```
// Create file metadata including the content type
var metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg').put(file, metadata);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, i missed this one the docs